# Spring component fields thread safety

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a web browser game and I want to ask about thread safety.
Let's say we have a domain classes (database entities) User and MyBuilding:

```
class User
{
public String name;
List<Building> myBuildings = new ArrayList<Building>();
}
```

and

```
class MyBuilding
{
public int buildingId;
public int level;
}
```

Now, a user want to get e.g. buildings health point.
I have another class which stores information about those building specification, that does not need to be stored in database, they are just 'building specification' classes and are initialized at the start of web application from xml files. E.g.:

```
@Component
class BuildingSpecificationHolder
{
public List<BuildingSpecification> buildings = new ArrayList<BuildingSpecification>();
}
```

// below class is NOT a Spring component, just a simple class

```
class BuildingSpecification
{
public int getHealthPointByBuildingLevel(MyBuilding usersBuilding)
{
return usersBuilding.getLevel() * 10;
}
```

And now my question is: Is the
'public int getHealthPointByBuildingLevel(MyBuilding usersBuilding)'
thread safe ? If simultaneously defferent users want to get building hp, they all access
above described method, that is in NON-spring object. Notice, that all methods of 'BuildingSpecification' are read-only(a user never changes Building properties), however different users will pass to those method different 'MyBuilding' parameter. Only the class that holds those Buildings specification is a Spring Component.

Answer (score 4):

A program is thread-safe if it contains no data races. A data race occurs if a memory location is accessed by several threads in such a way that the order of accesses matter (for instance, one thread writes a field, the another threads reads it).

Put differently, thread safety is about coordinating access to mutable state by several threads. Therefore, if you only change an object's state during its initialization, and initialization completes before the object is made available to other threads, the object is trivially thread safe. Its sound like `BuildingSpecification` is such an object.

Method parameters, being for a particular invocation of a method by a particular thread, are only ever accessed by that thread, and hence always thread safe (Of course, if the method parameters refer to an object, that object may be accessed by another thread, even if the method parameter isn't). Technically speaking, method parameters are stored on the thread's stack, not the heap shared by all threads.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `getHealthPointByBuildingLevel` isn't thread-safe. Although Spring initialization happens in a single thread at startup, you still might see uninitialized values in another thread. It's very unlikely though.

Since you're not changing these specification classes, the easiest way is to make them immutable:

```
class MyBuilding
{
public final int buildingId;
public final int level;

// constructor which initializes all fields
}
```

Comment: Hmm I think you did not understand me correctly. 'MyBuilding' is not immutable because they contain fields about building level which can increase during playing. So I can't make them final. My point is, if the buildings list in BuildingSpecificationHolder are thread-safe, if they methods are accesed simultaneously.